# WooCommerce Subscriptions Get Active Members for a Product Variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to get all active subscribers (called members in the project) who bought a specific WooCommerce product variation.

I've tried several solutions found here but no one works for me. :(

Comment: This question is not nearly specific enough. What have you tried thus far? What were the results? What result are you hoping for? The SO community is not here to do your work for you, only to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution with wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product()